# Как правильно сопоставлять числительные с существительными, не имеющими рода?

Tags: числительные, род, количественно-именное-сочетание

Слова, не имеющие единственного числа, не имеют так же и рода. Например ножницы, сутки, брюки и т.д. Но как правильно сопоставлять с ними числительные, оканчивающиеся на 2, 3 и 4? Понятно, что двое ножниц, двенадцать ножниц, но дальше? Двадцать два ножниц? двадцать две ножниц? Двадцать двое ножниц? Можно, разумеется, два десятка и двое ножниц написать, но неужели покороче никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, конечно, использовать подобную конструкцию: «двадцать двое суток», однако это допустимо только в разговорном языке. В литературном языке единственным выходом будет лексическая замена либо грамматическая правка. Например, если слово «сутки» не употребляется в качестве термина, его можно заменить «днем», и тогда проблема решается просто: «двадцать два дня», «шестьдесят четыре дня». Если же важно точное употребление термина, необходимо перефразировать вызывающее затруднение выражение: «в течение двадцати двух суток».
В деловом стиле можно использовать конструкции со словом «штука»: «приобрести двадцать две штуки ножниц» или даже «приобрести ножницы в количестве двадцати двух штук». Правда, такие обороты отдают канцелярским душком, поэтому желательно использовать их только в официальных документах и ни в коем случае не в художественной речи — конечно, если нет соответствующего стилистического задания.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае, насколько помнится, употребляют слово "штуки": двадцать две (три, четыре) штуки ножниц. В других случаях используют иные слова, например "двадцать две пары брюк и т.п

Comment: Не ко всякому существительному легко можно добавить штуки или единицы. Например, сутки. Я, собственно, заинтересовался этим вопросом при прочтении статьи на Википедии про муравьёв. "Срок развития от яйца до рабочей особи составляет в среднем 38 суток, у половых особей — 42 суток." Не очень хорошо же написать или сказать что срок развития составляет 42 единицы/штуки суток.

Comment: В таких случаях заменяют на "сорок два дня"

Comment: "Пара брюк (ножниц)" часто говорят (настолько часто, что у меня лично это выражение протеста не вызывает), но директивно рекоменловано ограничивать употребление "пары" случаями, когда сущность физически разделена на два предмета (обувь, носки и пр.). Видимо, это связано с проблемой однозначности учёта, напр. в торговле.